# Git log for getting changes in files and bug issues

Tags: git, github, git-log

So I want to get the informatino about the changes in a git repository. I used the following command:

```
git log --name-only --oneline --pretty="%h,%an,%ci,%s" --decorate=full > change_log.csv
```

It will save the information in csv file but the file name is not in the same line in the CSV file.
[image]

**1. How can I change the format to get the file names in the next cell after the title?**
**2. I also want to get the log for faults log that gives the following information, but not sure how can I get that using git log?**
[image]

and **3. how can I get the log information for bug issues:**
[image]

Comment: What if commits have more than one file or zero files?

Comment: the zero files can be empty. but if it has more than 1 file we can have multiple rows with the same commit hash

Comment: for #3 you probably need a perl script to retrieve this info from the bugtracker

Answer (score 0):

Answer for #1

The problem with git log output is that some fields of a commit can contain CSV field separator, newlines and quotes. CSV requires such values to be surrounded with double quotes `"` and the quotes inside should be duplicated:

```
aaa,"bbb1""bb
b2",ccc
```

[image]

Git can only do the escaping for the file names, but not for the other fields. Consider this log:

```
commit 4822fc186476b923e6a3a4758983898a4f799cdc (HEAD -> master)
Merge: 7f74ea0 e9d6448
Author: Joe <joe@acme.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 22 10:29:10 2020 +0300

    Merge branch "dev"

commit e9d644831f6c36a98f6868cde76ec2d259d5bc5c (dev)
Author: Joe <joe@acme.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 22 10:28:35 2020 +0300

    commit in side branch

some.txt

commit 7f74ea0542f70d67b51fdf97115ba473b7866c60
Author: Joe <joe@acme.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 22 10:27:37 2020 +0300

    added file with newline

"file\nwith\nnewline.txt"

commit 7a6f4cd0321d92c24e0b8051e8707d83b7d2fce0
Author: Joe <joe@acme.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 22 10:26:27 2020 +0300

    brief message

    detailed message

first file.txt
second file.txt

commit ed4370fb6349f4209c0014c02900af17573d74a0
Author: Joe <joe@acme.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 22 10:25:16 2020 +0300

    root
```

This is why you need an additional program to convert git log output into CSV.

I said that commit fields can contain CSV separators, but they probably can't contain nul character `'\0'`. We can use that.

From `git help log`:

```
   -z
       Separate the commits with NULs instead of with new newlines.

       Also, when --raw or --numstat has been given, do not munge pathnames and use NULs as output field terminators.

       Without this option, pathnames with "unusual" characters are quoted as explained for the configuration variable core.quotePath (see git-config(1)).
```

So with nuls the output looks like this:

```
$ git log --name-only --pretty="tformat:%h%x00%an%x00%ci%x00%s" -z
4822fc1^@Joe^@2020-12-22 10:29:10 +0300^@Merge branch "dev"^@e9d6448^@Joe^@2020-12-22 10:28:35 +0300^@commit in side branch^@
some.txt^@7f74ea0^@Joe^@2020-12-22 10:27:37 +0300^@added file with newline^@
file
with
newline.txt^@7a6f4cd^@Joe^@2020-12-22 10:26:27 +0300^@brief message^@
first file.txt^@second file.txt^@ed4370f^@Joe^@2020-12-22 10:25:16 +0300^@root^@
```

Notice that you can't get rid of newlines between the formatted message and the files list.

Now how to distinguish files from the next commit? I guess the only way is to use some magic string as the commit prefix: `--pretty="tformat:COMMITMAGIC%x00%h...`

Git for Windows comes with **gawk** and **perl**. I prefer gawk for simplicity. Here's the final script:

```
git log --name-only --pretty="tformat:COMMITMAGIC%x00%h%x00%an%x00%ci%x00%s" -z | gawk -v RS="COMMITMAGIC." -v FS="\0" '
  function esc(s) {
    if (s ~ /[,"\n]/) s = "\"" gensub(/"/, "\"\"", "g", s) "\""
    return s
  }
  /./ { # /./ skips first blank record
        commonpart = esc($1) "," esc($2) "," esc($3) "," esc($4) ","
        gsub(/^\n/,"",$5) # get rid of newline before file list
        for (i=5;; i++) {
          print commonpart esc($i)
          if (i>=NF-1) break
        }
      }
  '
```

[image]